# Android/java bad practice to leave multiple file streams open?

Tags: java, android, performance, file

I'm working on an app for root users, that frequently reads system files in /sys/devices/system/cpu...

I have two main questions, i'm using RandomAccessFile to read, then call seek(0) and leave the stream open for the next call. Is RandomAccessFile the correct class to use for this? or is there something better?

question 2, I have 8 instances of RandomAccessFile opened to read files in a seperate thread (for quad core device, 4 for cpuN/online to tell if core is online, then 1 for each cpuN/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq = 8). These files are read every 1000 ms, so I figured leaving them open is better than opening and closing 8 file streams every second. Is this bad practice or bad for memory hogging?

Comment: I think it's OK as long as you close them eventually, or maybe while the application is passivated or whatever the term is.

Comment: Yeah, you have to be careful (caveat I'm not an expert at Android programming--hence a comment not an answer).  My understanding is that the Android OS will keep a process active for "as long as possible".  With that in mind, I would think you should close your streams and, maybe more importantly, _not_ assume the streams are still open on subsequent invocations.

Comment: p.s. If you are doing something every second, I can't imagine that the process of gaining access to the file (i.e. putting an entry into the File table) would have much impact on performance.